# tryentercritical section undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, winapi

I get error TryEnterCriticalSection undeclared identifier during compilation.  Visual studio knows about the function but the compiler does not.  Other Critical Section functions are defined.  I have included `#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0400` in stdafx.h per msdn.  Definition in winbase.h is surrounded by `#if(_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0400) #endif /* _WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0400 */`
straight c++, XP, Visual Studio 6

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where have you defined the _WIN32_WINNT symbol in the stdafx.h file? Is it before the #include <windows.h> line? If not then the symbol will be undefined in winbase.h.

Comment: @matt: I have the define immediately b4 the include windows.h in stdafx.h.  I noticed I had another include for windows.h in the .cpp file also; I removed that and the problem cleared up.  Go figure.